# APS.NET MVC4 - how to get password in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a new account using Web Security class, now I want to get the password of that account in its original rather than an encrypted form. How can I achieve this? I tried this but it throws an exception:

> EXCEPTION: Specified method is not supported

Here is my config file section:

```
<add name="SimpleMembershipProvider"
     type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"
     connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
     enablePasswordRetrieval="true" 
     enablePasswordReset="true" 
     passwordFormat="Encrypted"
     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
     requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
     minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
     passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
     applicationName="/"/>
```

Here is my code:

```
  MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(model.userName, false);
  password = u.GetPassword();
```

Comment: Which is the method that isn't supported? Have you used a debugger and step through your code?

Comment: "u.GetPassword()" method is not supported ,i also used debuuger